# Why Am I getting my ArrayList empty if I call it from another class?

Tags: java, class, arraylist, methods, parameter-passing

I am pretty new to Java, a small help will be highly appreciated.

## Things to know about my code

I have two classes.

1. First Class is called EvidenceBox.class
2. Second Class called Police.class

In EvidenceBox class, I have a method called getParticularEvidence()

```js
    public ArrayList <Evidence> getParticularEvidence(int caseNumber, String evidenceType) {
      EvidenceBox e = new EvidenceBox(caseNumber, evidenceType);
      return e.getEvidenceByType(caseNumber, evidenceType);
    }
```

What this method is doing doing is that it is taking caseNumber and evidenceType as parameter. Inside this method we are creating an Object instance of EvidenceBox class so that I can call another method called getEvidenceByType() which is in EvidenceBox Class. The whole point of this method is to take those two arguments above and pass it to another method in another class which has an if statement inside for loop that checks if the arguments is equal to something inside an ArrayList called evidenceBoxList, if it is equal then return the list of Evidences that were equal.

When I invoke this in the Main class:

```js
System.out.println(crimeBoxOne.getEvidenceByType(2005000381, "S.Avery"));
```

What it does, is that it goes to the getEvidenceByType method, and then calls the other method which is in Evidence class:

```js
    public ArrayList < Evidence > getEvidenceByType(int keyNumber, String keyName) {
      ArrayList < Evidence > setOfEvidence = new ArrayList < > (evidenceBoxList);
      for (Evidence e: setOfEvidence) {
        if (this.getCaseNumber() == keyNumber) {
          if (this.getCaseName().equals(keyName)) {
            System.out.println("Pieces of DNA Evidence in Evidence Box number " + this.getCaseNumber() + " found by " + this.getCaseName() + ": " + this.getEvidence());
            getEvidence().add(e);
          } else {
            System.out.println("Not found!");
          }
        } else {
          System.out.println("Not Found!");
        }
      }
      return getEvidence();
    }
```

The getCaseNumber is the number of the EvidenceBox, and the getCaseName is the name of the evidenceBox

## My Problem

My problem is that The return of the list is always empty, even though it isn't because I added the EvidenceBox to the ArrayList. How can I resolve this problem?

getEvidence() is the getter method that returns the list of evidenceBox.

Here is my EvidenceBox class:

```js
package looselycoupled;

import java.util.*;

public class EvidenceBox {
  private int caseNumber;
  private String caseName;
  private ArrayList evidenceBoxList;

  public EvidenceBox(int caseNumber, String caseName) {
    this.evidenceBoxList = new ArrayList < Evidence > ();
    this.caseNumber = caseNumber;
    this.caseName = caseName;
  }

  public ArrayList < Evidence > getEvidenceByType(int keyNumber, String keyName) {
    ArrayList < Evidence > setOfEvidence = new ArrayList < > (evidenceBoxList);
    for (Evidence e: setOfEvidence) {
      if (this.getCaseNumber() == keyNumber) {
        if (this.getCaseName().equals(keyName)) {
          System.out.println("Pieces of DNA Evidence in Evidence Box number " + this.getCaseNumber() + " found by " + this.getCaseName() + ": " + this.getEvidence());
          getEvidence().add(e);
        } else {
          System.out.println("Not found!");
        }
      } else {
        System.out.println("Not Found!");
      }
    }
    return getEvidence();
  }

  public void add(Evidence getTypeFromEvidenceClass) {
    evidenceBoxList.add(getTypeFromEvidenceClass);
  }


  public ArrayList < Evidence > getEvidence() {
    return evidenceBoxList;
  }



  public void printRecordsOfTheEvidence() {
    Set < Evidence > setOfEvidence = new HashSet < > (evidenceBoxList);
    for (Evidence e: setOfEvidence) {
      System.out.println(Collections.frequency(evidenceBoxList, e) + "x " + e);
    }
  }

  public int getCaseNumber() {
    return caseNumber;
  }

  public String getCaseName() {
    return caseName;
  }

  @
  Override
  public String toString() {
    return caseNumber + " " + caseName;
  }
}
```

and Police class:

```js
package looselycoupled;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Cop {
    private String name;
    //private ArrayList collectionOfEvidences = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<EvidenceBox> collectionOfEvidences = new ArrayList<>();
    public Cop(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void copTakesAnEvidenceBox(EvidenceBox box) {
        collectionOfEvidences.add(box);
    }

    public ArrayList<Evidence> getParticularEvidence(int caseNumber, String evidenceType) {
        EvidenceBox e = new EvidenceBox(caseNumber, evidenceType);
        return e.getEvidenceByType(caseNumber, evidenceType);
    }

    public ArrayList<EvidenceBox> getEvidence() {
        return collectionOfEvidences;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code of `getEvidence()`. One of the problem with your code is that the `if conditions` i.e. `if (this.getCaseNumber() == keyNumber)` and `if (this.getCaseName().equals(keyName))` are always true since you are comparing the same values you set to the object and passed to the function. Shouldn't you be doing `e.getCaseNumber()` and `e.getCaseName()` instead?

Comment: this is the getEvidence():

    public ArrayList<Evidence> getEvidence() {
        return evidenceBoxList;
    }

Comment: Where/how do you add elements to `evidenceBoxList`?

Comment: this is the add method:
@user140547

`    public void add(Evidence getTypeFromEvidenceClass) {
        evidenceBoxList.add(getTypeFromEvidenceClass);
    }
`

Comment: You are iterating over `setOfEvidence` list. But the `add()` method will never be called if this list is empty which I guess it initially is.

Comment: @user2004685

But the setOfEvidence has EvidencBoxList:
`ArrayList<Evidence> setOfEvidence = new ArrayList<>(evidenceBoxList);`

Comment: @Naseebullah Do we have any elements in `evidenceBoxList` initially?

Comment: @user2004685 
Yes
The Array is not empty if i call it from EvidenceBox Object instance. But it is empty if i call it from Police Object instance with the method above

Comment: Where is `evidenceBoxList` and how are you adding elements to it?

Comment: @user2004685

In my EvidenceBox class, I have `private ArrayList evidenceBoxList;` and then I instantiate it in my constructor `evidenceBoxList = new ArrayList<Evidence>();`

If I were to add it. I would do something like this:

`EvidenceBox e = new EvidenceBox(1,"check");`
`e.add(object);`

Comment: @user2004685

Ive edited my class above. Check the code above please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`evidenceBoxList` is private to `EvidenceBox` class.

Whenever you are doing `EvidenceBox e = new EvidenceBox(caseNumber, evidenceType);` it is creating a new Blank instance of this list with no values.

Next you are iterating this list and trying to add a value using the following piece of code:

```
ArrayList < Evidence > setOfEvidence = new ArrayList < > (evidenceBoxList);
    for (Evidence e: setOfEvidence) {
      if (this.getCaseNumber() == keyNumber) {
        if (this.getCaseName().equals(keyName)) {
          System.out.println("Pieces of DNA Evidence in Evidence Box number " + this.getCaseNumber() + " found by " + this.getCaseName() + ": " + this.getEvidence());
          getEvidence().add(e);
        } else {
          System.out.println("Not found!");
        }
      } else {
        System.out.println("Not Found!");
      }
    }
    return getEvidence();
  }
```

Now since you initially have no elements in the `evidenceBoxList` it will never go in the `for` loop and will never call `add()` method.

The `getEvidence()` method is then returning this blank list to you.

Add `getEvidence().add(new Evidence(keyNumber,keyName));` before the for loop to verify the problem.

```
ArrayList < Evidence > setOfEvidence = new ArrayList < > (evidenceBoxList);
    /* Add Here */
    getEvidence().add(new Evidence(keyNumber,keyName));
    for (Evidence e: setOfEvidence) {
        /* Rest of the code */
```

Now, it should return you the list with one object.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I tried what you asked me to do. However, now it only returns the Evidence that I have added
`getEvidence().add(new Evidence(keyNumber,keyName));`

What about the arbitrary number of Evidence that I'de like to add?

Comment: I just explained the problem. You need to modify your code to achieve what you are trying to achieve. Probably try making `evidenceListBox` global.

Comment: Ah, Thank you so much. I really appreciate your response. You win the point